# Invoke-RestMethod special characters in credentials

Tags: rest, powershell

I'm trying to make an API call using a password that contains an "@" character and I'm getting invalid credentials.

```
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$Creds = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList $Username, $Password
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri ("http://contoso") -Credential $Creds
```

Comment: Have you tried `-Credential "$Creds"`?

Comment: -Credential "$Creds" does not work

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the special chars or put the password in single quotes.

But as @Lieven Keersmaekers said - the @ is no special char.
So you have to look if you have an other problem :)

Examples:

```
$Password = '$up@r'   // -- This works (single quotes wont interpret the "special chars")
$Password = "`$up@r" // -- This works because you escaped the characters
$Password = "$up@r" // -- This wont work
```

More Examples:

```
PS > $Password = "H@ppy"
$Password
H@ppy

PS > $Password = '$uper H@ppy'
$Password
$uper H@ppy

PS > $Password = "`$uper H@ppy"
$Password
$uper H@ppy
```

hava a look at this [Site](https://jorgequestforknowledge.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/passwords-containing-special-characters-in-powershell/)

Greetz Eldo.Ob

Comment: `@` is not a special char in a string. It's possible op has a $ though, we can't verify that but I doubt it. The first line already would error instead of the last one.

Comment: oh - your're damn right - @ is no special char - the error has to be an other

Comment: it was not the @ causing the problem it was in-fact a $ in the password causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it was not the @ causing the problem it was in-fact a $ in the password causing the problem.

I added single quotes to my password and it works.

Thanks for the suggestions.